# Java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException within docker container

Tags: java, docker, containers

I've created an application which creates files. The application works in intellij and when I export it as jar file. However when I create & run a docker container from it I get an Java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD ./initializr.jar initializr.jar
EXPOSE 8089
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "initializr.jar"]
```

And this is the directory I'm using

```java
private final String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\generatedFiles\\";
```

Normally it creates the generatedFiles folder if it's missing so I'm guessing the Systen.getProperty doesn't work?

Comment: Wild guess (I'm not a Java expert): since you're running inside a Linux container, \\ as path separator won't work. Try using / (or even better, something OS agnostic)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt That's most likely it, I'll have to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go inside the docker container and check if folder you are looking forward is exists. You can do it by `docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash`.
Also I think that for fs separators using `File.separator` is better.

Answer (score 1):

Unix uses '/' as path separator, try using

```
private final String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "generatedFiles" + File.separator;
```